# Functional tests running very slow when using Factory_Girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

In our Rails project, we decided to eliminate fixtures and use Factory_Girl for our tests instead. We program using TDD so we have plenty of unit and functional tests (Test::Unit). The application has 23 controllers and 14 models, which means that we have plenty of tests.

When we used fixtures testing was faster but we found that they were difficult to mantain (as our model associations began to grow).

Today, **TDD is becoming very difficult as running our full test suite takes about 50 seconds** (maybe this is not much) :-(

The following is one of the biggest Factories. Maybe there's something wrong with it that makes the object construction run slow...

```
Factory.define :content do |c|
  c.sequence(:id) {|n| n }
  c.title "Don't Make Me Think: A Common Sense Approach to Web Usability, 2nd Edition"
  c.description "Plain"
  c.privacy "private"
  c.category_id 2
  c.association :owner, :factory => :user
  c.file_file_name "file.abc"
  c.file_file_size 1024
  c.file_content_type "application/zip"
  c.cover_file_name "1.jpg"
  c.cover_file_size 200
  c.cover_content_type "image/jpeg"
  c.created_at "2010-01-01 00:00:00"
  c.opinions []
  c.creators []
end
```

**Anyone with experience in using Factory_Girl can tell us how to reduce our testing time?** Maybe there's something we can improve in our factories definition...

Thanks!

Pablo.

Comment: 50 seconds isn't really a long time for a full test suite.

Comment: Depend how test you are. If you are 10K test it's really quick. If you are 2 test it's really long. How test are you ?

Comment: Factory_girl is what is taking up all the time. I did some analysis on it today and it's responsible for .3 to .35 seconds per controller test! If you remove the Factory girl lines, each test runs immediately and only takes like .0001 seconds. It fails of course, but that's not the point. .35 seconds to build a few objects is insane - even for Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

We had a very long sample description in our Content's factory. By reducing the length of the test value for this field we've reduce the running time at almost 50%.

We're also asking ourselves if the fact that we're using acts_as_indexed in our Content model slows the execution of the test suite as contents are being indexed as they are created by Factory Girl. What do you think?

Thanks,

Pablo.

Comment: It seems highly unlikely that the length of a string-field impacts inserting (unless it is a huge amount, and by huge i mean several megabytes). It could also depend on your database. What database are you using? Aside of that, your `acts_as_indexed` seems the most likely culprit here.